# CSS In GitHub Pages not linking properly

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm working on a GitHub page, my first one, and I don't think my CSS is linking properly. The CSS won't show up on the page.
My repository: https://github.com/EnderCodesLol/endercodeslol.github.io/tree/main/rockpaperscissors

My page: https://endercodeslol.github.io/rockpaperscissors/

Any reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Add font size property instead of text-size . The css file is linked already

Comment: let me see it again

Comment: Its working bro.. you might forgot to refresh your page

Comment: Refreshed it many times now... I guess I'll just wait? Idk

Comment: WOAH! It just suddenly WORKED! I didn't even have to refresh! Weird...